# Jmeter distributed Testing - How does Ramp up time work in Distributed load testing

Tags: jmeter, distributed

If I run distributed testing in GUI mode with 4 client servers(1 Master + 3 Slave) and set the following values in my Plan -

```
Number of Threads = 12000  
Ramp Up time = 1000  
Loop count = 1
```

After completion of Test I get 36000 Samples (which is ok as `12000 * 3 = 36000`) but my question is for ramp up time - **will it be 3000 for 36000 users??
or will it remain 1000 for 36000**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be 1000, the same for all client.

Note such a load test profile seems strange as running only 1 request is not what happens with usual usage, what are you trying to simulate ?

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Actually I have used a Transaction Controller and in transaction controller I am Logging in to the system and navigating one other page.
We are trying to check simulation of 36000 users.

Your suggestion will be beneficial to me if you think I need to update my Test Plan.

Comment: If answer was helpful then you should accept it so that others can use it. Once you have enough points you can also upvote,